# utility to check app name availability in App Store

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios

Is there any object or code (javascript, php...) that can be integrated to check if an application name is available in the app store?

Comment: You have not mentioned which app store you are referring to ? Are you talking about Apple App Store ?

Comment: yes sorry, mainly apple app store and also interested in Android market

Comment: since people think App Store questions are OffTopic here we need a Stackexchange site for App Stores. Fortunately there is already a suggestion on area 51. [Commit here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores?referrer=jcBbxTFsYbhSPTdluUKgFA2)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a name is available for your app on Apple AppStore, you have to use itunesconnect website, and try to create a new application, it will ask you for the name, if it is not available you will not be able to proceed with the creation of it.

If you want to take the name, finish the creation of the application on itunesconnect, you can always edit it before to submit for the final review.